# Что значит аргумент flags в конструкторе SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, cursoradaper, параметры

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.text,cursor,s, new int[]{R.id.textView},0)
```

Последний параметр за что отвечает, написано "int flags". Флаг на что ?

Answer (score 2):

Это [флаги](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#constants) автообновления и установки слушателя на изменение данных.

[*FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) - при изменении курсора обновлять список автоматически, объявлен deprecated с API 11. Реальное значение константы = 1

[*FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) - устанавливает слушатель на изменение данных в курсоре. Если курсор будет изменен сработает колбэк [`onContentChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#onContentChanged()). Реальное значение константы = 2